# Bounty not given to to my good answer and is the only answer anyhow, what can I do?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

At the end I do not really care much. But I started wondering so I thought I ask.

I have answered a questions with +50 bounty and there was no one else that had any answer. The answer is good but it looks like the guy who asked who is a fairly new user never came back and did not care. What would I do? Was it all for nothing and just bad luck?

That is the post [MKMapKit regionDidChangeAnimated stops after tapping custom callout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957384/mkmapkit-regiondidchangeanimated-stops-after-tapping-custom-callout/11913954#11913954)

Comment: Since your answer doesn't meet the automatic assignment criteria (you needed at least 2 upvotes) there is nothing you can do.

Comment: The bounty was not offered by the original asker, but by a user named [ThePower](http://stackoverflow.com/users/67258/thepower?tab=bounties).

Comment: Sorry if this is a duplicate. The title of the other question did not make me think my question is answered there. @Martijn: Well thanks, that answers that. Automatic accepted on at least 2 upvotes. Uuuh, many found the question good but not the answer. Okay. Let's wait.

Comment: @hol I think you've misunderstood. The two upvotes have to arrive during the bounty period for the auto-award to kick in. You could get 100 upvotes now and you still wouldn't get the bounty. Also, it's customary on Meta to close posts as duplicates of FAQ entries that answer them, even if they're not literally duplicates. Regardless, welcome to MSO!

Comment: Thanks about pointing out that the other user offered the bounty. I was wondering.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that with the two upvotes. Well then. There is worse things in this universe then bounties not being awarded. :-) Thanks for all your help.